# Using protocol as type constraint on itself

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am using a protocol to define the core set of common properties to be shared across all `Items`.

```
protocol AnyItemable {
  ...
  var parentId: String? { get set }
  var parent: AnyItemable?
  ..
}
```

I also have a typealias to use as a generic where this needs to be identifiable and codable:

```
typealias Itemable = AnyItemable & Identifiable & Codable
```

Now, when I create any type of item, it implements the Itemable protocol:

```
struct PhotoItem: Itemable {
  // Protocol fields
  ...
  var parentId: String?
  var parent: AnyItemable?
  ...

  // Fields specific to this struct
  var photoUrl: String? 
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Type 'PhotoItem' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

I believe it's because protocols aren't inherently decodable? How might we resolve this? Our goal is to be able for any `Itemable` struct to be able to also have a parent that can be N number of types that conform to `Itemable`

Comment: Where is the code for `AudioItem`?

Comment: Sorry, meant that to be PhotoItem, updated

Comment: It might be a typo, but the struct also doesn't conform to Anyitemable.  The protocol  uses a `String` for `parentID` while the implementation uses a `String?` i.e. an optional string.

Comment: Can an `Itemable` have any other `Itemable` type as parent, or does each `Itemable` type has its own specific parent type?

Comment: Just commented on a very different question, but I think it applies here too. Why are you trying so much at once? `protocol`, 'typealias`, `struct`. If you could break it down some - just to debug - do you think it might help? (And I'm not even getting into the other stuff like `AnyItemable & Identifiable & Codable`. Seriously - break it down! I can't even say it's an issue with Swift. Get *something* that works broken down. Then edit your question.

Comment: In a `Codable` context any type must be a concrete type conforming to `Codable`. It cannot be protocol.

Comment: Further to Vadian's comment - Think about it - How could a protocol be decodable? What type is the system going to instantiate when it decodes?  There are a potentially infinite number of concrete types that could conform to your protocol.  Even if you just use inheritence from a base class rather than a protocol you are probably going to have problems decoding since you need to tell the decoder what the appropriate concrete type is for each item

Comment: So might PhotoItem be a generic parameterized on a concrete type constrained to Itemable?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I see now why a protocol can't be decodable, because... it's a protocol.

Comment: So my question is a Swift design question now — our model is as such: 

We are showing a list of mixed types called Items. We have a base Item that stores the common properties across all Items, i.e. createdAt, createdBy, parentId, etc.

Now, all of the "subclasses" (i.e. PhotoItem, LinkItem) have all the base properties, plus specific ones to their type.

I'd like to be able to create an array of mixed Items, and this has been working for us pretty well until I wanted to add the protocol (AnyItemable) as a type constraint on the protocol itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @matt Do you have an example of how that works?

Comment: What do you expect the JSON to look like that you're decoding? You've marked it Codable, so do you really mean it also has to be Encodable, or did you mean this to be Decodable only? Note that Identifiable is also going to bite you, since it has an associated type (ID) that could be anything Hashable. But as a starting point, what exactly do you expect the JSON to look like, particularly for `parent`?